# HTML hyperlinks will not redirect to the linked sites

Tags: html, hyperlink

I've been battling with this for hours now and I can't seem to find any information about the issue other than it might have something to do with Electron.

So the problem is this:

Earlier today while I was building my portfolio, I noticed that the hyperlinks weren't working, I tired recoding them, checked for any mistakes in my code, tried changing the target from blank to parent and nothing is working. The only way I'm able to get the hyperlinks to work is if I right click on them and select open link in new tab.

Aside from the hyperlinks not working, everything else on the page works, the dev tools in Microsoft Edge show no errors or accessibility warnings.

I decided to launch the page before finishing it to see if the problem would rectify itself but it's giving the same issue.

If you'd like to take a look at the site, the link is https://torrinbuildswebsites.netlify.app/ but please note, I have not added any media queries and the site was build desktop first so it'll probably be broken beyond use on mobile

My setup is VSCode with Node.js to compile Sass and run a live server in case that might help.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Share code, not a link to a website.

Comment: Sorry, I'll remember to do that next time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing your hyperlink and placing the image over it. Try wrapping the `<img>` tag with your hyperlink tag. Everything will work from there but you may have to adjust styling.

what you have:

```
    <a href="https://tbw-omnifood.netlify.app" target="_blank" 
    class="projects__grid--link"></a> <-----------------------ending hyperlink
      <img src="img/omnifood-logo.png" alt="Omnifood logo" 
    class="projects__grid--link--img">
```

what should work:

```
<a href="https://tbw-omnifood.netlify.app" target="_blank" 
class="projects__grid--link">
  <img src="img/omnifood-logo.png" alt="Omnifood logo" 
class="projects__grid--link--img"></a> <----------------end of hyperlink here instead
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had made a simple mistake  I really appreciate your help